# проблема с модальным окном bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

[ссылка на сайт](http://sjmania.ru/#section37)

Проблема такая, при нажатии на кнопку для открытия модального окна, весь контент как то дрыгается, как это убрать? убирал модалку в подвал (справа камера, у нее в подвале модалка).

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределите стили для класса `.modal-open` и добавьте следующее:

```
.modal-open {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: оперативно! спасибо!